# Bootstrap 5 Modal is not working How to make it work Smoothly

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Its a Bootstrap 5 Modal: I wanted modal to open after clicking on a Navbar Dropdown item Corporate Profile link, But It displays on load and after clicking on Nav dropdown item disables the whole website also on page load when it displays its close buttons are also not working. How to make it work correctly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active fw-bold" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    About
                                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Corporate Profile</a></li>

              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="#">Mission & Vision</a></li>

              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="#">CEO Message</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active fw-bold" aria-current="page" href="#">Product</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active fw-bold" aria-current="page" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navbar End -->
  <!-- Modal start -->
  <div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"></div>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal End -->


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modal’s not working because you’re closing the modal div in the first line. Remove the closing tag at the end of the line and your modal will work.

```
<!-- Modal start-->
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

One other note – you removed the `aria` attributes for the modal. Bootstrap’s example is:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Those attributes are helpful to enable the widest range of people to use your site.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <!--===================================================================================-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active fw-bold" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    About
                                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Corporate Profile</a></li>

              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="#">Mission & Vision</a></li>

              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item text-dark" href="#">CEO Message</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active fw-bold" aria-current="page" href="#">Product</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active fw-bold" aria-current="page" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navbar End -->
  <!-- Modal start -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal End -->


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```